# Weighted regression with 2 variables and interaction

Tags: r, linear-regression, weighted

I want to perform a linear regression with 2 continuous predictors (Y~X1*X2) and an interaction between them.
Moreover, i want to use weighted least square with « weights » argument. However the weight for X1 and X2 are different car i want to use their variance (var(X1) and var(X2)). I did that for each univariate regression.
I do not know how to perform that in a model including these 2 variables and their interaction term.
Coud you help me please ?

Comment: I'm unsure why you want to do this, but it's not as simple as specifying your weights to `lm`. In weighted regression you weight observations and not values. You could calculate average weights (e.g., the sum of the variances) for the observations.

Comment: Thanks you for you comment